# Start Merge Call using Obj C for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

My first question on Stack Overflow...

I'm trying to create an app that automatically merges an incoming call.  I can get the app to call the number I want but I can't seem to figure out how to trigger the "merge call" function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this from an iOS app on a non-jailbroken iPhone. The reason for this is that you have *very* limited access to anything outside your app's sandbox.

This access doesn't include actions other than placing a call.

If you *did* find a way to do so, your app would be rejected from the App Store by the review team. You would need to use private APIs to accomplish such a thing, and this would be a reason to reject your app.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but store acceptance is not the only factor. Some companies have enterprise licenses for deployment that circumvent the app store.